# Django busting /static content

Tags: django, mercurial

What will be the best stage in Django to append file timestamp to all urls which start with **/static/**?

Example URLs:

```
http://mydomain.com/static/css/...
http://mydomain.com/static/img/...
http://mydomain.com/static/js/...
```

Is there an app which does that and that will work with Mercurial VCS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

This app combines several CSS/JS files to the one file. And generates unique name for that file. For example:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/one.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">p { border:5px solid green;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/two.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
{% endcompress %}
```

Result will be something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/CACHE/css/f7c661b7a124.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```